# Ignore certain values when sorting React Tanstack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tanstack

I'm trying to make a sortable table that fills with sortable information. Some of the information could come back as `?` or `--` in either case, I'd like that value to be "ignored" and pushed to the end no matter the sort direction. I am using Tanstack and tried this simple sort function:

```js
const customSortingFunction = (rowA, rowB, columnId) => {
    const specialValues = ['?', '--']

    const valueA = rowA.getValue(columnId)
    const valueB = rowB.getValue(columnId)
    const isSpecialA = specialValues.includes(valueA)
    const isSpecialB = specialValues.includes(valueB)

    if (isSpecialA && isSpecialB) {
      return 0 
    } else if (isSpecialA) {
      return 1 
    } else if (isSpecialB) {
      return -1 
    }

    return valueA.localeCompare(valueB, 'en', {numberic: true})
  }
```

here's that column object as it exists in the list of columns:

```js
{
  accessorKey: 'location',
  header: 'Location',
  cell: props => <p>{props.getValue()}</p>,
  sortingFn: 'customSortingFunction'
},
```

Here's my Tanstack initialization:

```js
const table = useReactTable({
    data: buildTableData(data),
    columns: getColumn(vl),
    sortingFns: {
      customSortingFunction
    },
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    state: {
      sorting: sorting
    },
    enableSortingRemoval: false,
    onSortingChange: setSorting
  })
```

I know the function is being called when I sort by location through console.counts and logs, it sorts perfectly but also perfectly fails to ignore the ? and or -- values. I have tried changing the numbers that returns and many other functions. It just keeps sending ? to the top on desc no matter what I do. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: See https://github.com/TanStack/table/issues/476 - it looks like the direction is only available if you override the default sorting method.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a small typo in your localeCompare options. The correct option may be 'numeric' (not 'numberic'). Also, for better handling of special values, you may want to modify your custom sort function. Here is an updated version:

```
const customSortingFunction = (rowA, rowB, columnId) => {
  const specialValues = ['?', '--'];

  const valueA = rowA.values[columnId];
  const valueB = rowB.values[columnId];
  const isSpecialA = specialValues.includes(valueA);
  const isSpecialB = specialValues.includes(valueB);

  if (isSpecialA && isSpecialB) {
    return 0;
  } else if (isSpecialA) {
    return 1;
  } else if (isSpecialB) {
    return -1;
  }

  // Use `numeric` instead of `numberic`
  return valueA.localeCompare(valueB, 'en', { numeric: true });
};
```

Make sure to update your sorting function in the column definition as well:

```
{
  accessorKey: 'location',
  header: 'Location',
  cell: props => <p>{props.getValue()}</p>,
  sortingFn: customSortingFunction  // Not a string, directly assign the function
}
```

With these changes, your custom sorting function should work as intended, ignoring '?' and '--' values and pushing them to the end of the sorted list.

Comment: Hey, great catch on the typo! Thanks! However, it still did not work. Even if I directly assign the sorting function there. I think this may be a tanstack limitation, a pretty huge one to say the least. One thing, knowing the sort direction is pretty important for doing this, which cant be accessed as a prop. I made a state variable to reflect that and it still didn't work as expected. From what I could find, I have to manually manage the state and sort functionality of the data before it passes to Tanstack :( I really hope I'm wrong